# php store hours script, can't get midnight to work correctly

Tags: php

I have this simple store hours php script.

You add in the open hours of the store in the array.

Then you echo it out on the page.

However i have for example 10:00AM to 12:00AM.. and it breaks the logic.

Its supposed to say WE ARE OPEN... but it says we are CLOSED.

It works for every other time of the day.. but midnight something is wrong.

Please help? Probably something easy I am not seeing.

```
<?php        

date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');


$storeSchedule = [
    'Monday' => ['10:00 AM' => '11:00 PM'],
    'Tuesday' => ['10:00 AM' => '11:00 PM'],
    'Wednesday' => ['10:00 AM' => '11:00 PM'],
    'Thursday' => ['10:00 AM' => '11:00 PM'],
    'Friday' => ['10:00 AM' => '12:00 AM'],
    'Saturday' => ['10:00 AM' => '12:00 AM'],
    'Sunday' => ['10:00 AM' => '11:00 PM']
];


$timestamp = time();

$status = '<span style="color:#fc2323">Closed now</span>';

$currentTime = (new DateTime())->setTimestamp($timestamp);

foreach ($storeSchedule[date('l', $timestamp)] as $startTime => $endTime) {

    $startTime = DateTime::createFromFormat('h:i A', $startTime);
    $endTime   = DateTime::createFromFormat('h:i A', $endTime);

    if (($startTime < $currentTime) && ($currentTime < $endTime)) {
        $status = '<span style="color:#23fc41">OPEN</span>';
        $todayIs = "owen";
        break;
    }
}

echo '<p style="padding-bottom:5px;">Hours: ' . $status . '</p>';

foreach($storeSchedule[date('l', $timestamp)] as $openHour => $closeHour) { 

    echo "<p style='padding-bottom:15px' class=\"show-store-hours\">" . date('l') . ": " . $openHour . " - " . $closeHour . " &#43;</p>";

}

echo '<ul class="store-hours" style="margin: 0 auto; padding-bottom:25px">';

foreach ($storeSchedule as $storeDay => $hoursArray) {

    foreach ($hoursArray as $startTime => $endTime) {

        echo '<li>';
        echo $storeDay;
        echo ': <span>';
        echo $startTime;
        echo ' - ';
        echo $endTime;
        echo '</span></li>';

    }       

}

echo '<div class="clr"></div></ul>';
```

?>

Comment: That's because it's the next day but you are not accounting for that

Comment: 12:00 AM is the moment on which the date changes. In non-American units, that's 00:00:00. So if it's currently 11:00 PM (23:00:00), the store is not open, because `($currentTime < $endTime)` checks `(23:00:00 < 00:00:00)` which is not the case.

Comment: A simple workaround would be to open to 11:59 PM.

Comment: understood... is there an easy fix for this

Comment: check out twobrotherspizzaandpasta.com and scroll down.. the problem is.. it will say we close at 11:59pm then... supposed to be midnight... I guess I can do a jquery adjustment... but thats a hack... or is that all i got here?

Comment: A quick hack could be to change your operator from < to <= and change your closing hours to ex.: 11:59pm and then add 1 minute when printing your list.

Comment: If you don't feel like hacking it, you could condition your script so that if the closing time is < than the opening time, you compare full dates, adding 1 day to the closing time

Comment: Thanks I am going to try and hack it up and just adjust the time

Comment: $endTime   = DateTime::createFromFormat('h:i A', $endTime); <-- you could also substract the minute here and change  the operators to <=, it'd be even less trouble I guess.

Comment: You could use the `H:i` format to compare and format it to `g:i A` just to show out. See my answer for more details an example.

Answer (score 0):

How about trying to add 1 day to your endtime, if the endtime is midnight?  I think you're seeing this result because the time of midnight is literally less than all the start times.  For example, 10am to midnight on Friday is actually (time wise speaking) equivalent to 10am Friday to 12am Saturday.

There's another workaround too.  You could post your closing times as 11:59:59pm and display those times ad midnight.

To fix your endtime you could do

`if ($endtime < $starttime) {
        $endtime=date_add($endtime, INTERVAL 1 DAY);}`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the best workaround...

But this worked for me.. thanks for the help.

```
if ( $endTime == "11:59 PM" ) { 
 $endTime = "12:00 AM";
}
```

I echo this on the page, after I already stored the OPEN or CLOSED value.

Answer (score 0):

You could start with a `H:i` format string to compare the dateTime objects and then format them back to `g:i A`.

The difference is :

#### Midnight as `H:i`

```
$a = DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i', '24:00');
print_r($a);
```

> ```
> DateTime Object
> (
>     [date] => 2017-04-30 00:00:00.000000
>     [timezone_type] => 3
>     [timezone] => Asia/Dubai
> )
> ```

#### Midnight as `g:i A`

```
$a = DateTime::createFromFormat('g:i A', '12:00 AM');
print_r($a);
```

> ```
> DateTime Object
> (
>     [date] => 2017-04-29 00:00:00.000000
>     [timezone_type] => 3
>     [timezone] => Asia/Dubai
> )
> ```

So, you can do something like :

```
$a = DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i', '10:00');
$b = DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i', '24:00');
$c = new DateTime();
var_dump($c > $a && $c < $b);
```

> bool(true)

And to format the dateTime object back to the "12:00 AM" format :

```
print($b->format('g:i A'));
```

> 12:00 AM